# Html link to nginx location

Tags: html, nginx, nginx-location

I am new to web development so apologies if this is a simple question.  I have an nginx reverse proxy setup properly and am trying to create a link on my index.htm page that takes me to the reverse proxied site.

So if my website is "website.com" I want to link my nginx /test location to "website.com/test.  If I have the href as "website.com/test" it'll take me to the proper page but doesn't show the distinction in the browser address.

Because I am new to this I am unsure how to proceed and don't seem to be searching for the right terms.

Comment: The whole point of the reverse proxy is that you pull content from a different endpoint, and display it as if it were coming from the reverse proxy server.  If it is showing you the content from the reverse proxied site, then it is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Location blocks are used for processing request based on `request_uri` at the server level. So you can define a `location` block with prefix or equal to **test**, which will be executed whenever the `$request_uri` has prefix **test** or is **test**.

```
server {
   ...
   location = /test {
      ##do the required action
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
   ...
}
```

But you might not need this, if the requirement is just to run your project. Because when a user hits a url, they just have to be served index.html(if your project runs on it) which can be served in default `location` block with prefix `/`  as well. Then the index.html will be rendered on browser, and make other required requests, say for js or css. The request for js and css shall also be served from the same `location` block depending on your `root` value(if all files are kept in same directory and are matched with the `request_uri`).

```
server {
   ...
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
   ...
}
```

The above config is able to serve index.html to the users for all the urls or `request_uri`, and also the other file request.

You need to calculate your requirement and try them accordingly.

References: [How Nginx process request?](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)